# mutex locking order c++11

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mutex

I have a (fairly easy) question about `std::mutex` in c++11:

Suppose 6 threads want to lock the same mutex using `std::lock_guard`. Thread 1 ask for the lock, after which, thread 2 does the same, etc, until all 6 of them asked for the lock. The first thread to get the lock will make the 5 other threads block until the lock is available for each of them.

Now does the 5 other threads will be receiving the lock in the order they asked for it? Even though they all asked for it, can we take for granted that thread 2 will be the next one to receive the lock, or one of the thread may starve?

Comment: There's no guarantee. Once the first thread releases the lock, one of the blocked threads will get it - it's unspecified which one.

Comment: perfect , many tks for the answer !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mutex lock/unlock order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684155/mutex-lock-unlock-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will get the mutex in an undefined order.